# Authentication WP API with JWT switching method

Tags: wordpress, authentication, jwt, wp-api

I have a basic WP site set up with the WP API 2 (beta13.1) and JWT plugins. If I make a call to the `/token` endpoint while i'm already logged into WP, I get a successful response.

However, if I'm not logged in, I get a `"No route was found matching the URL and request method"` message.

Upon further digging I can see in my servers access logs that the POST request is getting recieved as a GET request, so must be getting changed somewhere along the line, hence the error message I am seeing!

```
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Jun/2016:16:19:04 +0000] "GET /test/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token HTTP/1.1" 404 450 "http://localhost/test/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0"
```

If I add a valid "wordpress_logged_in" cookie to the request, it works fine.

I can't figure out whats happening, the request to login a user shouldn't require the user to already be logged in!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just incase anyone else stumbles upon this question, the issue for me was Varnish. 
If you have `return (lookup)` in the Varnish config, then in an attempt to cache the the request, it get converted to `GET`

See: https://serverfault.com/questions/563560/varnish-transforming-post-to-get